# Multiple Rows and Columns in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a jquery code that displays results in one row and multiple columns as follows

```
function () {
    var i = noDays;
    var days = 30;
    while (i < days) {
        $('tr').append('<td> ' + i + ' </td>');
        i++;
    },
}
```

When I have more than 10 results (10 columns), the row stretch outside the page

How can I divide the row into multiple rows for instance?

if I have 30 columns in 1 row
I would like to instead have 6 columns and 5 rows

Comment: Why there is a `,` after `while()`?

Comment: Are you sure a `table` is the best presentation for this data? And on what criteria should your script move to a second row? What is it that you're presenting?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am presenting no. of days like day1, day2 etc ofcourse with additional data I have not added here. The criteria for moving to the next row should be no. of columns e.g a row should have a maximum of 6 columns

Comment: Like @DavidThomas was saying, it usually doesn't make sense to have columns from the same row on top of each other. Rather than having your row loop back to the start when it gets really wide, I think you should put your table inside a scrollable container, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RustyTheBoyRobot/TZMGR/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where you're appending the data, but look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kdst5/1/ - using the modulus operator on "i" can tell you when you to move to a new line; Additionally, instead of using `$("tr")`, you should use a specific selector, not necessarily the variable that I used, but something more specific than a general "every TR" selector.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create an element and use a reference to it, as opposed to having jquery fire off a selector in every pass.

Here is a working solution and its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/Kt4GV/1/):

```
var $table = $("#myTable");
var i = 1;
var days = 30;
var $tr = $("<tr>");
while (i <= days) {
    $tr.append('<td>' + i++ + '</td>');
    if (i %6 == 1) {
        $table.append($tr);
        $tr = $("<tr>");
    }
};
$("#myTable").append($tr);
```